# Perl: Build a hash without a predefined number of key columns?

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to write a function that will read a delimited file (think something like /etc/passwd) and return the values in a hash. The delimiter, column names and key columns will be specified as parameters to the function, the last two passed as array references. It will return a reference to a hash.

I'd like to allow both single and compound keys, but I can't figure out the best way to create the hash when I don't know the depth of the keys beforehand.

For example, suppose I specify 4 columns: A, B, C, and D, and two key columns: A and D. To assign values from a single line in the file, we'd have something like:

```
$var->{A value)->{D value)->{A} = A value;
$var->{A value)->{D value)->{B} = B value;
...
```

However, if I specify only a single key column (B), it would look like:

```
$var->{B value)->{A} = A value;
$var->{B value)->{B} = B value;
...
```

What would be a way to generalize this without knowing the number of key columns prior to execution?

Comment: Could you be more specific, that is, show some actual examples of input, the expected output for each input, and perhaps some code you have tried so far?

Comment: @haukex, The input for both examples is the string produced by `join($sep, "A value", "B value", "C value", "D value")`

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't be better to use `$var->{"avalue dvalue"} = { A => avalue, B => bvalue }`? That way the key is just `join ' ', avalue, dvalue`.

Comment: Also, which of the columns is supposed to be in the bottom-level hash? You seem to have `A` and `B` in both cases, but nothing is passed to the subroutine to select these two.

Comment: @Borodin I considered using delimiter-separated key values as a single hash key, but as a database guy, that just rubs me the wrong way. It also makes it difficult to list sub-keys when given just the top key, without iterating through the entire hash.

Comment: @Swechsler: *"as a database guy, that just rubs me the wrong way"* So you never use compound keys in your databases? *"It also makes it difficult to list sub-keys when given just the top key"* Is that something you need to do? You need to list all the accesses that you require and design your data structure from there. It's quite possible just to store all the records as an array of arrays of fields, and create separate hashes that index that array by all the required keys.

Comment: @Borodin A compound key would be [key1, key, key3], not [key1+key2+key3]

Comment: @Swechsler: That's a petty and irrelevant distinction. You're talking about internal implementation now.

Comment: @Borodin Not at all. Here's a simple example of how they're different.

With discrete keys (e.g. key1, key2, key3) I can perform the action
 '' keys %{$data->{key1}} ''
and see all the subkeys for key1; however, with an appended key I can't do that without additional logic and a regular expression match.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );

my @key_col_names = ...;
my @col_names     = ...;

my $data;
while ( my @row = ... ) {
    my %rec; @rec{@col_names} = @row;
    my @keys = @rec{@key_col_names};
    DiveVal($data, map \$_, @keys) = \%rec;
}
```

You can use the following instead of `DiveVal($data, map \$_, @keys) = \%rec`:

```
sub dive_val :lvalue {
   my $p = \shift;
   $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_;
   $$p
}

dive_val($data, @keys) = \%rec;
```

Comment: This could work, although ti's a PITA to get any new modules installed on our systems. Is there a native Perl solution?

Comment: I'm thinking that the easiest (although ugly) solution might be to have separate cases for a reasonable number of key nestings (say, 4 or 5) that I might ever have. But I would still like to know if there is a "good" way to do it.

Comment: If you can install a script, you can install a module. No special permissions are needed. That said, see update.

Comment: Now that I've had a closer look, I'm confused by this. Does $data refer to the current row being read? If so, how do I combine all the rows into a single hash reference? Also, how do I get the (compound) key of the row just read/assigned?

Comment: $data is what you called $var